# How to fix LanmanServer and srvnet error?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, file-sharing, smb

We have a PC running Windows7 Enterprise. The PC can access the Internet and communicates with other workstations (i.e: I can RDP connect to it), but it cannot access any file shares.

I tracked down the problem, and it looks like the LanmanServer service won't start. It always gives error 1068 - which means that dependancies failed. However, it has only one service as dependancy and it's running. The other dependancy is an SMB driver (srvnet), and this might be the culprit.

I tried to reinstall and update network drivers, tried to delete and reinstall File and Printer share service on the NIC and tried to run sfc /scannow which found and corrected some corrupt files, but didn't solve the issue.

I also found this article: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2316513
But I don't know if this will help. Although I'm gonna check the PATH variable.

Any suggestions? I want to avoid reinstalling the PC if possible.